# Is there any way to pass the focus back to parent window tab from child window in firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

Is there any way to pass the focus back to parent window tab from child window in Firefox and IE.

Following code works fine in Chrome and closes the child window as well. But in Firefox and IE it passes focus only when there in single tab in parent window. If multiple tabs are there and some other tab is in front then it do not change the focus to the desired parent window tab which is the original window tab that had opened the child window.

```
function onButonClick() {
            var win = window.open('', window.opener.name);
            win.focus();
            open(location, '_self').close();
        }
```

Comment: Try window.opener.focus();

Comment: window.opener.focus() works in Chrome but not in Firefox or IE

Comment: Strange, I'm mainly a IE9 dev and I have no issues with using window.opener. No idea about firefox though.

Comment: Issue is in multiple tabs case, when the parent window tab is not in front.

Comment: Explain a bit more when the focus should go back to the parent window. Upon closing the child tab? Directly after opening it? Even with 10 tabs open in IE9, each of them seems to have a window.opener reference back to the parent window, so explain a bit more and show the code that puts the focus back on the parent. Btw, aren't you like overwriting your own reference with `open(location, '_self').close();` ? What is this piece of code supposed to do?

Comment: Focus should go back to parent window when child window is closed by clicking on a button(not the toolbar close button), that says "Go to parent application".   open(location, '_self').close(); this code is there for closing the childwindow.

Comment: So the child window should probably have the event handler. Have the button on the child page do: `window.opener.focus()` folllowed by `window.close()`.

Comment: Not working in multiple tabs...

Comment: Did some research and apart from some 'alert' hacks I can't get to work, this isn't possible unless your browser has a specific setting for it. Try looking into opening a new window (by using `window.open('','','modal=yes')` instead of a new tab. Or show your extra tabs inside the same page with popovers.